# Proof that distinct numerator polynomials are equal for all x when over the same denominator polynomial

Tags: calculus, continuity

I am just curious about this part of the proof.

The question is this:

Suppose that F, G, and Q are polynomials and 
$\frac{F(x)}{Q(x)}=\frac{G(x)}{Q(x)}$ for all x except $Q(x)$ = 0

Prove that $F(x)=G(x)$ for all x

The question does not say it but I believe this to be an identity because of where in the textbook I was referred to do the exercise. (Partial fractions)

The Solution:  Argues that both F and G do not agree at a finite number of x values.  However, the continuity of F and G as polynomials means that they agree at those values of x too.

It shows this example when Q(a)=0

$F(a) = \lim_{x\rightarrow a}F(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}G(x)=G(a)$

However, the middle part is only true when Q(x) does not equal 0.  So even though it is getting sufficiently close to 0 it is still not acceptable at 0 itself.  How can I say they are equal?  Or is it now acceptable at 0?

Isn't F(x) and G(x) the same curve by the way because they are equal at all values of x?

Wouldn't it be true even with  a limit that they would be equal to each other but there would be a discontinuity at x when Q(x) = 0 at x=a?

Comment: Since you can clear the denominator $Q(x)$ for all but finitely many $x$, you have $F(x)=G(x)$ for infinitely many $x$.  And two different polynomials can be equal at at most finitely many points.  QED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can clear the denominator $Q(x)$ for all but finitely many $x$, you have $F(x)=G(x)$ for infinitely many $x$.  And two different polynomials can be equal at at most finitely many points.  QED

Comment: The question does not say, but I think it should be an identity because of where in the textbook it referred me to the problem.  Wouldn't F(x) = G(x) for all values of x and be equal at infinitely many points?  Or am I misunderstanding what an identity is?

Comment: I agree with your proof, but why does the book use continuity if it can be explained so succinctly by clearing the denominator?

Comment: An identity between functions $F(x)=G(x)$ does mean they have the same domains and the equality holds for all $x$ in the domain of definition of the two functions.  The identity $\frac{F(x)}{Q(x)}=\frac{G(x)}{Q(x)}$ (where all functions are polynomials) therefore would implicitly hold for all $x$ except those for which $Q(x)=0$ at which neither side is defined.

Comment: I guess because all you really need is that $F$ and $G$ are continuous at the points where $Q(x)=0$ to conclude $F(x)=G(x)$ for all $x$.  We used an extra property of polynomials having only a finite number of zeros, but in reality you only need $F$ and $G$ continuous.

Comment: So would the graph of F(x) and G(x) be the same because they are equal at every value of x in the domain?

Comment: Yes the graphs would have to be exactly the same everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  I think I am just not comprehending continuity to understand the proof.    it is the F(x) = G(x) by continuity I am struggling with.

Comment: Suppose $Q(x_0)=0$.  Then the continuity thing just says that since $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ agree at all $x$ arbitrarily close to $x_0$ then they must agree at $x_0$ too.  If they weren't continuous you couldn't draw that conclusion.  Discontinuous functions could agree in all $x$ arbitrarily close to $x_0$ but then not agree at $x_0$ itself.

Comment: So with continuous functions it can be predicted that getting very close to $x_0$ will give the value of the function at $x_0$.  This is a result of them being continuous.   I think I somewhat understand.  Continuity and limits are intertwined.  A discontinuous function is one where the limit does not approach the defined value.

Comment: So if I know that they are equal to each other and they both approach arbitrarily close to $x_0$,  then they will actually be equal to $G(x_0)$ and $F(x_0)$.  That is $G(x_0)$ value is defined.  I fear I am going around in circles with all this though.

Comment: A polynomial of positive degree n takes the value zero at at most n points . If F and G agree at infinitely points then F(x)-G(x) is a polynomial that is zero at infinitely points,  so it must be of degree 0, that is, a constant  K, and since  0=F(x)=G(x)=K for some x, we have F=G.